# Aliasing of a surface plot with imagesc() in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, surface, antialiasing

I am trying to create a surface plot of a matrix in Matlab. For the purpose, I have so far found that the imagesc() function in Matlab is probably my best choice, however, I have trouble with undesired aliasing in the plots.

I.e. when zoomed-out the data is not represented accurately which could be misleading. For e.g. the "yellow stripes" in a fully zoomed-out image appear to be occurring only in some columns:

[image: Fully zoomed-out plot]

However, this is not the case as once zoomed-in the data is displayed correctly:

[image: Zoomed-in section]

Could someone give a hint whether imagesc() has any hidden undocumented parameters which could be tweaked to solve this aliasing problem?

Comment: I'm not very hopeful on this suggestion, but did you try changing the figure's renderer? Use `set(gcf, 'Renderer')` to see the list of existing renderers, then change it with something like `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')`